# Android image transparency

Tags: android, image, transparency

How can I make certain pixels of an DrawableBitmap transparent?

Comment: I have the same issue. Need to replace white background of png Bitmap to transparent.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps:

```
Bitmap buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
buffer.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: It will change all pixel's color. I need to make transparent only few pixels.

Comment: The Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 has been deprecated because of the poor quality of this configuration, it is advised to use ARGB_8888 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports transparency on PNG files. So convert your bitmap to a PNG using an editor like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and the work's done for you.

Comment: I have to do this programmatically. I do not know the images to advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the underlying Bitmap (if it is mutable) pixel with the setPixel method.

Comment: it may be a very long and expensive. There is not a filtering system that makes it ?

Comment: Depends on how pixels in the image you want to change at every frame.
What is the underlying bitmap size? How much of it do you want to change? 1% 10% 50%?

There are many filtering classes in android.graphics but they do not operate on pixel basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
.setAlpha(alpha)
```

`alpha` can range from 0 (fully transparent), and 255 (fully opaque).